# Adding multiple conditions in conditionalPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I was wondering if it is possible to add more than one condition in `conditionalPanel` in shiny. This is an example:

```
 conditionalPanel(condition = "input.SELECT == 1",
                   #Slider 
                   sliderInput("D_FLAG", "Parameter X:",
                   min = 0.001, max = 3, value = 1.38, step = 0.1))
```

I want to add another condition (other than `input.SELECT==1`). I have tried this but it didn't work.

```
conditionalPanel(condition = c("input.SELECT == 1","input.FED==2"),
                   #Slider 
                   sliderInput("D_FLAG", "Parameter X:",
                   min = 0.001, max = 3, value = 1.38, step = 0.1))
```

but it didn't work. I would appreciate if somebody could have some input on the right way for including multiple conditions in the `conditionalPanel` above.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can have as complicated of a statement as you want as long as it evaluates to TRUE or FALSE at the end. You probably want to combine your two conditions either with AND `&&` or OR `||`, like this (for OR):

```
"input.SELECT == 1 || input.FED == 2"
```