# Multiple conditions in condition panel R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to have multiple conditions when using  conditionpanel  in aa r shiny app? I want to hide a particular UI component for a couple of tabs. Below is what I am trying but it doesn't seem to be applying  when I have multiple conditions:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tab",
              menuItem("1", tabName = "1"),
              menuItem("2", tabName = "2"),
              menuItem("3", tabName = "3")
  )
)
body <-   ## Body content
  dashboardBody(box(width = 12,fluidRow(
    fluidRow(  column(
      width = 3,  textInput("text1", label = h5("Min"), value = "1")),
      column(
        width = 3, textInput("text2", label = h5("Max"), value = "2")),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.tab !== '2' || input.tab !== '3'" , column(
        width = 3, textInput("text3", label = h5("Max"), value = "3"))),
      column(
        width = 3, textInput("text4", label = h5("Max"), value = "4")))

  )))

ui <-   dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Scorecard"),
                      sidebar,
                      body)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$op <-renderDataTable({
    df_format()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding multiple conditions in conditionalPanel in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488924/adding-multiple-conditions-in-conditionalpanel-in-shiny)

Comment: The duplicate question has two seperate inputs.In my question both are the same.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but where the condition comes from doesn't matter: multiple conditions can be written to a conditional panel using that syntax. If it's still not working, there may be another issue - a reproducible example would help id.

Comment: Just added a reproducible example

Comment: `condition = "input.tab !== '2' && input.tab !== '3'"` causes a conditional panel because there are only 3 panels. The way you had things written, the condition was always `TRUE`. You're issue is one of logic from using the `OR` operator not multiple conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @RyanMorton said, the problem was that you used an `OR` when you should have used an `AND`:

```
condition = "input.tab !== '2' || input.tab !== '3'"
```

is `TRUE` when the tab isn't 2 or isn't 3, which is always. By changing it to:

```
condition = "input.tab !== '2' & input.tab !== '3'"
```

changing the tab to 2 or 3 is enough to make the statment `FALSE` and hide the tab